# How to pass Object to controller using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having one modelform

```
public class ABC
{
private String a;

private String b;

private Obj obj;

...getteres and setters.....
}
```

in my jsp my OnSubmit function is

```
function showMethod(rowid) 
{
    document.diamondSingleStoneLabForm.action = adminUrl + "/act.htm";
    document.diamondSingleStoneLabForm.suid.value =value1;
        document.diamondSingleStoneLabForm.obj.value = tempObj;

    document.diamondSingleStoneLabForm.submit();
}
```

**now, my question is**

How to pass Object  to specified action..???

Or How to pass obj.name property value (I cant access it using document.diamondSingleStoneLabForm.obj.name.value = nameVal;)..???

Answer (score 2):

Hope in your jsp page you have a text field like this :

```
<input type="text"  name="obj" value="<%= rs.getString(n)%>" >
```

but you should tally with the modelform & jsp(this will be your logical part) page where from you fetch the value like `<%= rs.getString(n)%>`

then you can do this thing

```
var obj = obj_value;
var action = adminUrl + "/act.htm";  
document.diamondSingleStoneLabForm.action = action ;
document.diamondSingleStoneLabForm.submit();
```

Or you can use: `jQuery.post()` method in this format

```
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

you can take a look of this link: [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: If you want to fetch the dynamic value,then,<1> Where from you get the value of those instance variables ? <2>How do you relate Modelform with your jsp.I should check these things,you can briefly explain these things in your Ques.